How to concatenate all further columns from duplicated items of a first column?
In Google Sheets I have two or more columns of data:

Column 1 is a list of items that may include duplicates.
Column 2 (and any additional columns), contains keys each associated with the item  from the same row.

I want to return a two-column array where:

Column 1 is a list of unique items
Column 2 is a comma delimited value made by joining all the unique keys associated with the item from that row.

Example A:  One Key Col




A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Item
Key


Item
Key


2
foo
apple


foo
apple,orange


3
bar
apple


bar
apple,orange


4
foo
orange






5
bar
orange






6
bar
apple








Data in A:B.
Results in E:F.
E:E contains unique items fromA:A
Keys for bar in F3 contain only one of the duplicates fromB3 and B6

Example B:  Multiple Key Cols




A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Item
Key
Key2

Item
Key


2
foo
apple
grapes

foo
apple - grapes,orange - apple


3
bar
apple
plum

bar
apple - plum,orange - test


4
foo
orange
apple





5
bar
orange
test





6
bar
apple
plum







Data in A:C.
Keys includes both Columns B and C.
Keys for foo in F2 contain only one of the duplicates fromB2 and C4

Current Formulas

For the items results column I have:
=UNIQUE(A1:A)


For the keys results column, starting from Row 2, I have:
=JOIN(",", FILTER(B:B, A:A=E2))
=JOIN(",", FILTER(B:B, A:A=E3))
=JOIN(",", FILTER(B:B, A:A=E4))
=JOIN(",", FILTER(B:B, A:A=E5))
=JOIN(",", FILTER(B:B, A:A=E6))



New Formula Needed
My data is dynamic and I don't want to add a new formula for every new row of data.
I also don't want to have to edit the existing formulas if another keys column gets added or one is removed.
I'm looking for a single formula that will perform all the calculations while ignoring blank rows and skipping duplicates.
I tried the following unsuccessfully:
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",", FILTER(B:B, A:A=FILTER(E2:E, E2:E<>""))))

Which formula can I use to return the results I described in Google Sheets?
Note that I have a similar Excel specific question on Super User.

The source is just external and arrives like that. Regarding the multiple version (second table), in column E there should be just 3 responses, no more. Each of them has the items from column A with their matches from both B and C. Regarding your answer, let's discuss it in the answer's comments, continuing there.

I updated my answer to use CHOOSECOLS   for the key array, which will adjust to the number of Key ColumnS, kcs, you include in your range. eg. A1:B=1kcs, A1:D=3kcs, {A1:B;D1:D}=2kcs

Thanks, I've modified the examples because you've changed the principle of x-y,a-b to x,y,a,b.

I'm worried it'll be deleted nonetheless for being too similar. Is there any chance you'll add to the existing answer anyway a multiple key version? I've signaled your answer as accepted either way.

No, neither is expected.

I've updated the formula to join the key columns on a dash.

Brilliant update! Is there a chance you also have a non 365 and non Power Query solution for the similar Excel question (linked in the question)?

I'm not a big Excel user but if I get a chance to look at it I will. It's a lot more challenging without the newer functions.

Thanks, by now I've also added there a VBA UDF Macro solution, so everything but native functions. :-)

Formula
=LET(arr,QUERY(A1:C, "WHERE Col1 <> ''", 1),
   itm,INDEX(arr,,1), kcols,CHOOSECOLS(arr,
     SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(arr)-1,2)),
  key,BYROW(kcols, LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN("-",1,r))),
   BYROW(UNIQUE(itm), LAMBDA(r, 
     {r, TEXTJOIN(",", 1, UNIQUE(FILTER(key, itm=r)))})))

Explanation

LET is used to store intermediate calculations in named variables.
arr is an array created from the range of items and keys columns after removing rows with no item.

Column 1 is always the list of items
Column 2 - Column ? are keys columns associated with the item on the same row.


itm stores the items column from arr.
kcols stores the keys column(s).
key stores kcols after first applying TEXTJOIN to each row delimited by a dash - using BYROW.
Lastly another BYROW passes each unique itm, one-by-one into a LAMBDA function that stores the current row in r.
For each r passed in, the LAMBDA's formula returns a two-column array:

The first column is r
The second is a text string made by joining all the values from key delimited with a comma , where itm=r while skipping blanks.




You've updated your answer to switch from FILTER to QUERY ("This will make it easier for you to add and remove ranges while using the same basic formula."). It looks simpler indeed, but works just the same, i.e. it handles the singular column case and not the one with multiple columns. In the latter case there should be just 3 responses, which are the items from column A with their matches from both B and C in the same response. Just as shown in the question's second table.

Was hard to follow the new requirements as was the original question but I have adjusted the formula  to address what you want, and edited the question to make it clearer.

Thanks, but you've also edited to change the principle of x-y,a-b to x,y,a,b, so I've had to fix. Can you adjust the formula?

Thanks for updating and wow!
